# How to delete from JSON Object using dynamic path using JQuery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I have a JSON Object "person" and i need to delete a key "age" which should be passed as a parameter to a function as the example given below. Inside the function the statement to delete the key is added as `delete person+key;` but its not working. Please suggest the way to delete the key in the below manner, as i have to delete the keys dynamically on the "p" element click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          var person = {
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe",
            age: 50,
            eyecolor: "blue"
          };
          function funToDelete(key){
            delete person+key;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.";
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p onclick="funToDelete('.age')">Click me</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `delete person[key]`.

Comment: Dont pass the parameter as '.age. instead use just 'age' and when deleting, use delete person[key] (person['age'])

Comment: I have added a simple JSON example above. But in my actual case the Object is complex and dynamic so i need to pass the object path ".category[1].additionalinfo"(just an example) to remove an element which is inside the object

Comment: Pass key dynamically while calling fuction write like to delete key `delete person.key;` and if you pass keys like person.firstname, person.age etc which wants to print that will be print `undefined`

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator with square bracket notation:

```js
const person = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyecolor: "blue"
};
const key = 'age';

delete person[key];

console.log(person);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use [] operator instead of +. Because you want to access a property in an Object using a variable. The code should be

```
delete person[key]
```

The square brackets notation is used to access the property of an Object using variable names or expressions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
          var person = {
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe",
            age: 50,
            eyecolor: "blue"
          };
          function funToDelete(key){
            delete person[key]; // This is where the key gets evaluated to a sting
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.";
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"></p>
        <p onclick="funToDelete('age')">Click me</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation `[]`:

```
delete person[key];
```

Call just like this:

```
funToDelete("age");
```

Demonstration:

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyecolor: "blue"
};

function funToDelete(key) {
  delete person[key];
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p onclick="funToDelete('age')">Click me</p>
```

Note - since you're removing `age`, the above shows `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

When you want access key by a variable use **[Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation)** .
you should `delete[key]`
pass only `age`as parameter not `.key`

```js
var person = {
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe",
            age: 50,
            eyecolor: "blue"
          };
          function funToDelete(key){
            delete person[key];
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
            person.firstname + " is " + person.age + " years old.";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
        <p onclick="funToDelete('age')">Click me</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on this `OP` comment:

> I have added a simple JSON example above. But in my actual case the Object is complex and dynamic so i need to pass the object path ".category[1].additionalinfo"(just an example) to remove an element which is inside the objec

A more generic approach could be pass the `key` path, `split()` it by `dot` and use `reduce()` to get the key to delete:

```js
var person = {
  firstname: "John",
  lastname: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyecolor: "blue",
  foo: {bar: "something"}
};

function funToDelete(pathToKey)
{
    let keys = pathToKey.split(".");

    let toDelete = keys.reduce((acc, key, idx, arr) =>
    {
        if (idx < arr.length - 1) acc = acc[key];
        return acc;
    }, person);

    delete toDelete[keys[keys.length - 1]];
    console.log(person);
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<p onclick="funToDelete('foo.bar')">Click me</p>
```